# What does these variable names stand for?

Tags: javascript

I am using a function which have some variables that I don't know what they stand for.

*The variables are:*

```
a   //From var a = Math ...
```

and

```
The d in dLat
```

Here is the code:

```
function checkDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
      var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
      var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
      var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
      var a = 
        Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
        ; 
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
      var d = R * c; // Distance in km
      return d;
    }
```

What do you think they stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function which uses the *haversine* formula to calculate the Earth surface distance between two points (using the points' latitude and longitude values).

```
 a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2) 
 c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) ) 
 d = R ⋅ c
```

The "d" in `dLat` stands for the *delta* Δ (aka the difference between the two latitudes). This is just what the variable was called in this function. The `dLat` is equivalent to `Δφ`, while `dLon` is equivalent to `Δλ`.

The `a` variable is equivalent to the first line of the formula.

I hope this answers your question.

You can find more info here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html